# Get specific variables from over 900 text files

Tags: javascript, node.js

## The problem:

- I have over 900 text files with the same content in each one, except for 5 different variables (each text the name is different, the URL, etc
- I want to get all of the variables from these text files and add them to an excel sheet, so I can later upload as CMS content on a website
- I know javascript, but never do very complex things with it

## The Question:

Where do I start, is there any library that does anything similar, If I do it manually, it will take too long to get it right since I'm not very proficient in this kind of thing

.

Here's a template of the text files:

```
+++
title = "Get the best out of {{in_name}} and {{out_name}} with company_X"
subtitle = "Receiving important {{in_name}} events {{out_preposition}} {{out_name}} has never been easier"
seoTitle = "Connect {{in_name}} and {{out_name}} with company_X's on-call and alerting features"
description = "Connect {{in_name}} and {{out_name}} or extend events from {{in_name}} with voice calls, push notifications, on-call schedules and more life cycle management"
tags = [
]
date = "2021-03-17"
categories = [
]
image = ""
lpCookieVal = "{{cookie_val}}"
+++

Add on-call features and alert prioritization between {{in_name}} and {{out_name}}.
By taking advantage of company_X's advanced two-way alerting and on-call scheduling capabilities,
our self-service integrations can help you bring the best out of {{in_name}} and {{out_name}}.

And while you are at it, company_X can not only help you to make sure that you only receive the events which you
really need, but also to easily extend events from {{in_name}} with voice calls, push notifications, SMS
on-call schedules and additional life cycle management.

Take a look at [{{in_name}} integration guide]({{in_doc_url}}) for detailed instructions on how to integrate {{in_name}} and
at [{{out_name}} integration guide]({{out_doc_url}}) for detailed instructions on how to integrate {{out_name}} with company_X.

When choosing to setup your flow between {{in_name}} and {{out_name}} with the help of company_X you will also benefit from updates
of our cloud alerting platform on a regular basis.

Start in minutes and connect {{in_name}} and {{out_name}} with company_X's intelligent cloud alerting platform.

In case you have any questions or require a custom integration for your product, feel free to reach out to us, we are looking forward to help you with your inquiry.
You can reach us per email, chat or phone just take a look at the contact information in the footer of this website.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us exactly what you want to extract from your sample text file. Sample input and sample output, please. And, it happens that the PERL language is made for this kind of Pathologically Eclectic Rubbish Listing :-) task, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

To be more concise, I'll just use this as a file template example:

```
Hello {{in_name}},
You can reach us at {{email}}, {{{in_name}}}
Best regards
```

It contains the same variable multiple times, sometimes with double curly braces, sometimes triple, like in you example. You'll just need to paste your text in place of it.

The first step would be to spot the variables in that template, and create a Regular Expression to grab them. You could create a very simple function to do so:

```js
function createCustomRegex(template) {
  const varNames = [];
  const regexTemplate = template.replace(/\{+(\w+)\}+/g, (_, varName) => {
    if (varNames.includes(varName)) {
      return '.*'; // If the variable already exists, don't try to match it
    } else {
      varNames.push(varName); // Otherwise, add it
      return `(?<${varName}>.*)`; // And make it a named group
    }
  });
  return new RegExp(regexTemplate);
}

const template = `Hello {{in_name}},
You can reach us at {{email}}, {{{in_name}}}
Best regards`;

const regex = createCustomRegex(template);

const exampleString = `Hello Mister Banana,
You can reach us at mr.banana@gmail.com, Mister Banana
Best regards`;

console.log(exampleString.match(regex).groups);
// { in_name: "Mister Banana", email: "mr.banana@gmail.com" }
```

Then, the file handling logic. In this example, I grab all the filenames from a directory, read them all in a loop and apply the regex to them. It outputs an Array, which is then converted to CSV using [Papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');
const Papa = require('papaparse'); // Requires to npm install papaparse

// The path to the directory storing the files relative to this script.
// For example, if there is a "data" dir next to this file:
const dirPath = Path.join(__dirname, './data/');
const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

// Will contain [{name: 'Bob', email: 'foo@bar'}, {name: 'Eve', email: 'baz@baz'}, ...]
const data = fileList.map((file, i) => {
  console.log(`#${i+1} out of ${fileList.length}: ${file}`);
  const contents = fs.readFileSync(Path.join(dirPath, file), 'utf-8');
  return contents.match(regex).groups;
});

// Convert the Array to CSV
const csv = Papa.unparse(data);

// Save it to a file
fs.writeFileSync(Path.join(__dirname, 'result.csv'), csv);
```

## The final script

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');
const Papa = require('papaparse'); // Requires to npm install papaparse

// The path to the directory storing the files relative to this script.
// For example, if there is a "data" dir next to this file:
const dirPath = Path.join(__dirname, './data/');
const fileList = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

const template = `Hello {{in_name}},
You can reach us at {{email}}, {{{in_name}}}
Best regards`;
const regex = createCustomRegex(template);

// Will contain [{name: 'Bob', email: 'foo@bar'}, {name: 'Eve', email: 'baz@baz'}, ...]
const data = fileList.map((file, i) => {
  console.log(`#${i+1} out of ${fileList.length}: ${file}`);
  const contents = fs.readFileSync(Path.join(dirPath, file), 'utf-8');
  return contents.match(regex).groups;
});

// Convert the Array to CSV
const csv = Papa.unparse(data);

// Save it to a file
fs.writeFileSync(Path.join(__dirname, 'result.csv'), csv);
console.log('Done');

function createCustomRegex(template) {
  const varNames = [];
  const regexTemplate = template.replace(/\{+(\w+)\}+/g, (_, varName) => {
    if (varNames.includes(varName)) {
      return '.*'; // If the variable already exists, don't try to match it
    } else {
      varNames.push(varName); // Otherwise, add it
      return `(?<${varName}>.*)`; // And make it a named group
    }
  });
  return new RegExp(regexTemplate);
}
```